# DelegateCommand RefreshCommand to refresh ObservableCollection-bound DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection, delegatecommand

I'm trying to update my `DataGrid` (name: dgLicenseholder, bound to an `ObservableCollection`. I am using `MVVMLight`) when I add new rows to the database.
Why isn't this working?

In my `ViewModel`, I have a `public DelegateCommand RefreshCommand {get; private set; }` and a method:

```
private void Refresh() {

    licenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolders());
}
```

`licenseHolders` is a ObservableCollection list, which looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<LicenseHolders> licenseHolders { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolders>();
```

`LicenseHolders` is a class in my `Model`, that holds the data:

```
public class LicenseHolders {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Foretaksnavn { get; set; }
    // more like the above...
}
```

In the XAML, I've bound the command to a button like so;

```
Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgLicenseHolder}"
```

My method to update the database is placed in the `ViewModel`, and called by a click-event in the code-behind for the window holding the `DataGrid`.

**AddToDB()**

```
NewLicenseHolder nlh = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<NewLicenseHolder>().FirstOrDefault();

try {

   using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new(connectionString))
   using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new(sqlString, sqlCon)) {

        sqlCon.Open();
        
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foretaksnavn, nlh.txtForetaksnavn.Text.ToString());
        // more of the above...
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

### Question 1:

What's wrong with the way I've bound my `RefreshCommand`? My method to add to the database works fine, but I have to re-open the window for the `DataGrid` to "catch" the change.

### Question 2:

How can I bind the method I use to update the database without putting it in a click-event?

## UPDATED CODE (trying to implement solution suggested by user ChrisBD)

***LicenseHolder.cs - holder class (Model)***

```
namespace Ridel.Hub.Model {

    public class LicenseHolder {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Foretaksnavn { get; set; }
        public string Foretaksnummer { get; set; }
        public string Adresse { get; set; }
        public int Postnummer { get; set; }
        public string Poststed { get; set; }
        public string BIC { get; set; }
        public string IBAN { get; set; }
        public string Kontakt { get; set; }
        public string Epost { get; set; }
        public string Tlf { get; set; }
        public string Kontonummer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***RidelHubMainViewModel.cs (ViewModel)***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using Ridel.Hub.Model;

namespace Ridel.Hub.ViewModel {

    public class RidelHubMainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }

        public ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder> LicenseHolders { get; set; }

        public RidelHubMainViewModel() {

            RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteRefreshCommand);
            LicenseHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder>();
            FillDataGridLicenseHolders();
        }

        private void ExecuteRefreshCommand() {

            NewLicenseHolder nlh = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<NewLicenseHolder>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (LicenseHolders == null) {

                LicenseHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder>();

            } else {

                AddToDB();
                LicenseHolders.Clear();
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Foretaksnavn = nlh.txtForetaksnavn.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Foretaksnummer = nlh.txtForetaksnr.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Adresse = nlh.txtAdresse.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Postnummer = Convert.ToInt32(nlh.txtPostnummer.Text.ToString()) });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Poststed = nlh.txtPoststed.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { BIC = nlh.txtBIC.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { IBAN = nlh.txtIBAN.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Kontakt = nlh.txtKontakt.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Epost = nlh.txtEpost.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Tlf = nlh.txtTlf.Text.ToString() });
                LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Kontonummer = nlh.txtKontonr.Text.ToString() });
            }
        }

        public void FillDataGridLicenseHolders() {

            // Initially populates my DataGrid with the Sql server table
            try {

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new(ConnectionString.connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new("select * from tblLicenseHolder", sqlCon))
                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDaAd = new(sqlCmd))
                using (DataSet ds = new()) {

                    sqlCon.Open();
                    sqlDaAd.Fill(ds, "tblLicenseHolder");

                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {

                        LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder {

                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString()),
                            Foretaksnavn = dr[1].ToString(),
                            Foretaksnummer = dr[2].ToString(),
                            Adresse = dr[3].ToString(),
                            Postnummer = (int)dr[4],
                            Poststed = dr[5].ToString(),
                            BIC = dr[6].ToString(),
                            IBAN = dr[7].ToString(),
                            Kontakt = dr[8].ToString(),
                            Epost = dr[9].ToString(),
                            Tlf = dr[10].ToString(),
                            Kontonummer = dr[11].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string myLicenseHolder) {

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(myLicenseHolder));       
        }

        private void OnLicenseHoldersPropertyChanged() {

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LicenseHolders"));
        }

        #region Slett løyvehaver
// How I delete rows from the DataGrid
        private static bool RemoveFromDB(LicenseHolder myLicenseHolder) {

            string sqlString = $"Delete from tblLicenseHolder where ID = '{myLicenseHolder.ID}'";
            
            if (MessageBox.Show("Er du sikker på at du ønsker å slette valgt løyvehaver?", "Slett løyvehaver", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes) {
                
                try {

                    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new(ConnectionString.connectionString))
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new(sqlString, sqlCon)) {

                        sqlCon.Open();
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return true;
                    }

                } catch {

                    return false;
                }

            } else {

                return false;
            }
        }

        private void RemoveLicenseHolderExecute(LicenseHolder myLicenseHolder) {
            
            bool result = RemoveFromDB(myLicenseHolder);
            if (result)
                LicenseHolders.Remove(myLicenseHolder);
        }

        private RelayCommand<LicenseHolder> _removeLicenseHoldersCommand;

        public RelayCommand<LicenseHolder> RemoveLicenseHoldersCommand => _removeLicenseHoldersCommand
            ??= new RelayCommand<LicenseHolder>(RemoveLicenseHolderExecute, RemoveLicenseHolderCanExecute);

        private bool RemoveLicenseHolderCanExecute(LicenseHolder myLicenseHolder) {

            return LicenseHolders.Contains(myLicenseHolder);
        }

        #endregion

        public void AddToDB() {

            string sqlString = "insert into tblLicenseHolder (Foretaksnavn, Foretaksnummer, Adresse, Postnummer, Poststed, BIC, IBAN, Kontakt, Epost, Tlf, Kontonummer) " +
                "values (@Foretaksnavn, @Foretaksnummer, @Adresse, @Postnummer, @Poststed, @BIC, @IBAN, @Kontakt, @Epost, @Tlf, @Kontonummer)";

            NewLicenseHolder nlh = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<NewLicenseHolder>().FirstOrDefault();

            try {

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new(ConnectionString.connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new(sqlString, sqlCon)) {

                    sqlCon.Open();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtForetaksnavn.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtForetaksnr.Text)
                        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtAdresse.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtPostnummer.Text)
                        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtPoststed.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtBIC.Text)
                        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtIBAN.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtKontakt.Text)
                        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtEpost.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtTlf.Text)
                        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nlh.txtKontonr.Text)) {

                        MessageBox.Show("Vennligst fyll ut alle tekstboksene.");
                        sqlCon.Close();

                    } else {                       

                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foretaksnavn", nlh.txtForetaksnavn.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foretaksnummer", nlh.txtForetaksnr.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresse", nlh.txtAdresse.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postnummer", nlh.txtPostnummer.Text);
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Poststed", nlh.txtPoststed.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BIC", nlh.txtBIC.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBAN", nlh.txtIBAN.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kontakt", nlh.txtKontakt.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Epost", nlh.txtEpost.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tlf", nlh.txtTlf.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kontonummer", nlh.txtKontonr.Text.ToString());
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                                                  
                        MessageBox.Show("Ny løyvehaver lagret. Husk å oppdatere listen.");
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***View, Code-behind - Parent-window (LicenseHoldersWindow)***

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Ridel.Hub.ViewModel;

namespace Ridel.Hub {

    public partial class LicenseHoldersWindow : Window {

        public LicenseHoldersWindow() {
            
             InitializeComponent();
             DataContext = new RidelHubMainViewModel();
        }

        private btnNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

             NewLicenseHolder newLicenseHolder = new();
             newLicenseHolder.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

***View, XAML - Parent-window (LicenseHoldersWindow)***

```
<Window
    x:Class="Ridel.Hub.LicenseHoldersWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ridel.Hub"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Ridel.Hub.ViewModel"
    Title="License Holders"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:RidelHubMainViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<!-- GUI stuff -->
<!-- also button to open new child-window "NewLicenseHolder" -->

<DataGrid
        x:Name="dgLicenseHolder"       
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"       
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding LicenseHolders, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectionChanged="dgLicenseHolder_SelectionChanged"
        SelectionMode="Single">
```

***View, code-behind- child-window (NewLicenseHolder)***

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using Prism.Commands;
using Ridel.Hub.ViewModel;

namespace Ridel.Hub {

    public partial class NewLicenseHolder : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {

        public NewLicenseHolder() {
            
            InitializeComponent();
            btnLogOut.Content = UserInfo.UserName;
            DataContext = new RidelHubMainViewModel();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void btnLagre_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        // Button: Save new LicenseHolder
           ((RidelHubMainViewModel)DataContext).RefreshCommand.Execute(null);
           this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

***View, XAML- child-window (NewLicenseHolder)***

```
<Window
    x:Class="Ridel.Hub.NewLicenseHolder"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Ridel.Hub.ViewModel"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:RidelHubMainViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<Button
      Name="btnLagre"
      Foreground="White"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
      Click="btnLagre_Click"
      Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
      Style="{DynamicResource ButtonWithRoundCornersGreen}" >
</Button>
```

Ok, so, if you read through all of this: God bless.
As you see, I add the new row-info in a child-form, click save, and ideally, would like my DataGrid to then be automatically updated (without clicking any additional "refresh" or "update"-buttton.

What happens now is, when I click save, I get a error:
`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Local1 was null.` inside my `AddToDB()`-method, at the `if-else statement` where I check that none of the textboxes are empty.
So there's obviously something wrong with the way I reference the `NewLicenseHolder class` inside of the `ViewModel`:

`NewLicenseHolder nlh = Application.Current.Window.OfType<NewLicenseHolder>().FirstOrDefault();`

How can I reference it properly, and make sure the DataGrid is updated when I leave my child form and go back to the parent form?

Many thanks, very appreciative for any guidance to correct my thinking!

Comment: Why would AddToDB() not directly update the licenseHolders collection? Why are you clearing the collection in Refresh before adding a new item? As a note, accessing `Application.Current.Windows` in a view model is clearly breaking the fundamental MVVM concept that a view model does not know the view.

Comment: Please show the xaml of your DataGrid including bindings. It is not obvious why you are Doing things the way you are as you should really just add new items to the ObservableCollection directly and save the new or changed ones via a delegatecommand  from the viewmodel not the view.

Comment: @T.Schwarz Hello, thank you for your comment. I have updated my question with the XAML for my DataGrid. I would really prefer to do things the most streamlined and simplest way, and would love your feedback.

Comment: @Clemens thank you for replying. What you say makes sense.
I would love for my AddToDB() method to directly update the collection, but I'm not sure how. It's to do with calling the `PropertyChanged`-event? I tried doing that, but it wouldn't let me. I will research it. I have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged`-interface in both the ViewModel and the windows code-behind.

Comment: You would just have to call `licenseHolders.Add(x);` where x is a newly created LicenseHolders object with all the properties properly set. The class LicenseHolders should be named LicenseHolder, because it is only a single license holder.

Comment: @Clemens like so?
`LicenseHolder addLicenseHolder = new LicenseHolder();
 licenseHolders.Add(addLicenseHolder);` in the AddToDB()-method?
This gives me a red squiggly under licenseHolders.
licenseHolders is the name of my ObservableCollection.
(PS: class name changed! :-))

Comment: Sure, but you have to set the properties of the addLicenseHolder object. I am also assuming that licenseHolders and the AddToDB method are in the same view model class.

Comment: @Clemens Hello again! So, I made some progress (at least I'd like to think so).
I set the properties like so: 
`LicenseHolder addLicenseHolder = new LicenseHolder();
 addLicenseHolder.Foretaksnavn = nlh.txtForetaksnavn.Text.ToString();
 // more like the above
 licenseHolders.Add(addLicenseHolder);
`
BUT -- I still get a red squiggly under "licenseHolders".

And yes, `public ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder> licenseHolders { get; }
      = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder>();`
is in the same ViewModel class as AddToDB method.

Comment: @Clemens ok, so, I added this:
`ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder> licenseHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder>();`

before the `licenseHolders.Add(addLicenseHolder);`

But it's still the same result. The row is added to the database table, but I have to re-open the window for the DataGrid to refresh. A break point at the last line reveals "Expression has been evaluated and has no value" So I am obviously missing something crucial, and probably very obvious.

Comment: That makes totally no sense. You would have to add an element to the existing collection.

Comment: @OleM: From where are you calling `AddToDB()` and how this related to the command?

Comment: @mm8 hello! thanks for your comment. the `AddToDB()` method is in the ViewModel. In the window with the `DataGrid`, I call it from a buttons click event. The button is bound like this:
`Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgLicenseHolder}"`

Comment: Did you verify that `Refresh()` is actually called when you click on the button?

Comment: @mm8 hi, thanks again for commenting. I actually hadn't. I just did, and it doesn't seem to be called at all..

Comment: Hi, I'd recommend that you create a new ViewModel for the LicenceHolder data type. Then when you want a new one i.e. you create the View to enter the information, you inject the new ViewModel. In fact your ObservableCollection can contain a list of LicenseHolder ViewModels - this makes it easier to display the data which is bound to by the individual LicenceHolder View

Comment: Hi, I think that the issue here is `DataContext = new RidelHubMainViewModel();` you should inject the instance instead by making your new window constructor `public NewLicenseHolder(RidelHubMainViewModel viewModel)` and then `DataContext = viewModel` this will allow you to reference the same data as your original view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that I may have confused MVVM frameworks - anyway here's some working code for MVVMLite.

```
   public class LicenseHolder
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        RefreshCommand = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf.RelayCommand(this.ExecuteRefreshCommand);
        LicenseHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder>();
    }
    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder> LicenseHolders { get; set; }
    private void ExecuteRefreshCommand(object o)
    {
        if (LicenseHolders == null)
        {
            LicenseHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenseHolder>();
        }
        LicenseHolders.Clear();
        //Code here for async retrieval of licence holder records from database 
        //and addition of new LicenceHolder instances to the LicenceHolders collection
        LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder(){Name ="Ted"});
        LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder(){Name = "Bill"});

    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModelAsDataSource" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding LicenseHolders }" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="License Holder Name" Width="Auto" MinWidth="18" Binding="{Binding Name }" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="Refresh" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" Width="50" Height="30"/>
     <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Content="Refresh" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Width="50" Height="30"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)DataContext).RefreshCommand.Execute(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @ChrisBD, much appreciated.
Sorry for not fully grasping this, but I have some additional questions.
You see, my app is built like so: parent-window with DataGrid -> click add -> new child-window opens, with textboxes for the addition of the new row. When I click save, the child-window closes, and the parent-windows DataGrid is supposed to be updated.
I am a bit confused in what is meant with async retrieval of license holders.
My ViewModel has a method in `public ViewModel()` called `FillDataGrid()`.

Comment: it seems your proposed solution is a way to both fill the DataGrid and enable the addition of a new row all-in-one? I am having a bit of trouble accessing the child-window, as it's out of reach and comes out null when I call the `ExecuteRefreshCommand`. I've instantiated it with a `ChildWindow ch = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ChildWindow>().FirstOrDefault();`
So its closed, so it can't do that, I presume. So it's not able to access the textbox values when I try to add `LicenseHolders.Add(new LicenseHolder() { Foretaksnavn = ch.txtForetaksnavn.Text.ToString() });`

Comment: Hi, the above demonstrates the binding between the DataGrid and the ViewModel.LicenseHolders collection (I've put in adding two rows in the ViewModel where your DB access would be called). It also shows how you can bind a button Click in the View XAML and calling the same Command using a button Click through the code behind.

Comment: I'm going to updated my question with the entirety of my code, not expecting you to reply again, but if you do, it'd be greatly appreciated. You should add a link on your bio accepting donos for coffee :-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay there's much that I don't see here on how the database code is linked to your code but this might help:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel() 
    {
        RefreshCommand = new Command(async()=> await ExecuteRefreshCommand());
        LicenceHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenceHolder>();
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<LicenceHolder> LicenceHolders { get; set; }

    private async Task ExecuteRefreshCommand()
    {
        if (LicenceHolders == null)
        {
            LicenceHolders = new ObservableCollection<LicenceHolder>();
        }
        LicenceHolders.Clear();

        //Code here for async retrieval of licence holder records from database 
        //and addition of new LicenceHolder instances to the LicenceHolders collection
    }
}
```

In the View XAML

`<Button Text="Refresh" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"/>` this will trigger the RefreshCommand

View code behind with ViewModel injection

```
public partial class SomeView : ContentPage
{
    public SomeView(ViewModel viewModel) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

otherwise

```
public partial class SomeView : ContentPage
    {
        public SomeView() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Ideally you'll want to use Commands to trigger events or processing in your ViewModel. This can be triggered by binding in the View as above or from the code behind like so

```
private void Button_OnClick(object sender, OnClickEventArgs e)
{
   ((ViewModel)BindingContext).RefreshCommand.Execute();
}
```

Strictly we should use a flag to indicate that the asynchronous DB access is ongoing - this can be achieved by use of a public boolean (flag) in the ViewModel that is used as a `CanExecute` condition in the Command instance creation, which will prevent multiple calls to the same code occuring until such time as its completed.
e.g.

ViewModel:
`bool IsBusy {get;set;}` set this true before calling your asynchronous data access routine and set false when completed

in the constructor, Command instantiation now becomes
`RefreshCommand = new Command(async()=> await ExecuteRefreshCommand(), ()=>!IsBusy);`

XAML binding will automatically pick this up, but if you're using code behind code to trigger the Command this becomes:

```
if (((ViewModel)BindingContext).RefreshCommand.CanExecute())
{
   ((ViewModel)BindingContext).RefreshCommand.Execute();
}
```

**Note:**
If you replace the `LicenceHolders ObservableCollection` with a new instance at runtime, rather than alter its contents then you will need to raise/invoke the `PropertyChanged` manually by calling an OnPropertyChanged handler.
e.g.

```
protected void OnLicenHoldersPropertyChanged()
{
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LicenceHolders"));
}
```

Comment: Hi, @ChrisBD, I am working on implementing your solution - thanks alot! But the BindingContext is not available to me. Visual Studio suggest adding a weird "com.sun.xml.@internal.ws.spi.db"-using statement, which I'm guessing is not right.
Any idea?

Comment: hi, @ChrisBD, thanks again, so where I'm at now is that when I call
`((RidelHubMainViewModel)DataContext).RefreshCommand.Execute(e);`
(I see you didn't add the 'e' there, why is that?)
I get a a System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Any idea why?

Comment: Hi, I'm glad that you've managed to get somewhere - I think that I may have used code using a different MVVM framework. I'll add an update.

Comment: You can pass `null` in the command call. I've added code below for a simple two button program that demonstrates using Galasoft MVVMLite commands.